# Complete normed vector space

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, approximation

I came across this question and was not sure how to proceed. Is the normed vector space of all polynomial functions on [0,1] complete with respect to the infinity norm? Thank you

Comment: Have you heard of the [Weierstrass polynomial approximation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Weierstrass_approximation_theorem)?

Comment: I have heard of it, but I'm not quite sure how to apply it here.

Comment: It states that any continuous function on $[0,1]$ is the uniform limit of a sequence of polynomial functions (and thus in the closure of your space). So, the question is: "Is there a continuous function on $[0,1]$ that is not a polynomial function?"

Comment: I see so since sin(x) is not a polynomial the space is not closed and thus is not complete?

Comment: If you consider the space as a subspace of $C([0,1])$, yes. As a space unto itself, you can argue that you have a Cauchy sequence (the sequence converging to $\sin x$) that does not converge. By the way, there are easier examples of continuous functions that are not polynomial functions (e.g., $f(x)=|x-1/2|$).